# How does Max know the audience ain't gonna see the first two shows without even taking a look at it?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, videodrome

In [Videodrome](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086541/), Max skipped the first two shows and demands the 13th show to be shown to him.

> Max: No, hold it. Uh, show me the last one.
>
> Max: Number 13
>
> Japanese Salesman: But you won't understand anything. Everything is
>   set up in the first two.
>
> Max: **My audience ain't gonna see the first two shows. Show me the last
>   one.**

How does Max know the audience ain't gonna see the first two shows without even take looking at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because series usually pick up fans along the way. They'll catch the show mid season and either be hooked or not care anymore. So, it's important for the show to be catchy at any episode.

As an example, Walking Dead Season 1, Episode 1, had 5.3 million US viewers on the premier. The end episode had nearly 6 million, over half a million more viewers. Season 7 premier had 17 million US viewers (so over 3 times as many viewers). Audience grows along the way. And they'll start in the middle, and only then go back and watch the first few episodes. This is specially true when TiVos, easily accessible pirate versions and streaming services weren't the norm.

[Source for numbers, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Walking_Dead_episodes#Season_7_.282016.E2.80.9317.29)